# Which projection type is most suitable for area calculation of northern hemisphere using arcgis/qgis?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, area

which projection will be most suitable for the area calculation of polygon which is almost covering the whole northern hemisphere?
I am trying to calculate the area of the historic distribution of brown bears so that's why I want to estimate the area of that polygon but its projection is in WGS1984 (Geographic Coordinate System) and in this projection, I cant calculate the area so I have to change its projection to Projected Coordinate system "GCS to PCS" and now I'm confused and I don't know which projection would be likely to cover Whole Northern Hemisphere!

Answer (score 4):

I would try Lambert azimuthal equal-area https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/properties/lambert-azimuthal-equal-area.htm

> **Distortion**
>
> Lambert azimuthal equal-area is an equal-area (equivalent) projection.
> Shapes, directions, angles, and distances are generally distorted.
> Scale and directions are true only at the center of the projection.
> The scale decreases with the distance from the center along the radii
> and increases from the center perpendicularly to the radii, resulting
> in small shapes compressed radially from the center and elongated
> perpendicularly. The general pattern of distortion is radial.
>
> **Usage**
>
> Although the Lambert azimuthal equal-area projection can display the
> entire globe, its practical usage is typically limited to a
> hemisphere. This projection is most commonly used for thematic mapping
> of polar regions. The oblique aspect is sometimes used for individual
> land masses that are symmetrically proportioned, either round or
> square.